# Send POSTs to a PHP script on a server

Tags: php, iphone, post, nsurlconnection

I have a PHP script on a server

```
<?php

// retrieve POST vars
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

// remove trailing whitespace etc
$comment = trim($comment);
$email = trim($email);

// format date accoring to http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp
$date_time = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s"); // i.e. 2010-04-15-09-45-23

// prepare message
$to = "(removed my email addy)"; //who to send the mail to
$subject = "Feedback from iPhone app"; //what to put in the subject line
$message = "Name/Email: $email \r\n Comment: $comment";
  mail($to, $subject,$message) or "bad";

echo "ok";
?>
```

How do I now send a POST request from my iPhone app...

ive tried this sort of thing...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mysite.com/script.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *message = boxForSuggestion.text;
NSString *userEmailString = usersEmail.text;


NSString *requestBodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comment:%@&email%@", message , userEmailString];

NSData *requestBody = [requestBodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"
[request setHTTPBody:requestBody];
 [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"]; // added from first suggestion 
NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
NSError *requestError = NULL;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
```

Any ideas? Thanks guys

Sam

EDIT:

i think there is something wrong with my request body

```
NSData *requestBody = [requestBodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"
[request setHTTPBody:requestBody];
```

remember that my php variables are $comment and $email

Comment: I don't know Objective C, nor any of the iPhone APIs, but you should set the correct MIME type (application/x-www-form-urlencoded). The POST data should basically be URL encoded: `key=value&etc`

Comment: how do i do that? Thorarin might not know... anyone else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add:

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
```

After:

```
[request setHTTPBody:requestBody];
```

In your script

Edit:

Since I don't have a sdk available I can't test it for you but could you try this?:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mysite.com/script.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 NSString *requestBodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comment=%@&email=%@", message , userEmailString];
 NSData *requestBody = [NSData dataWithBytes:[requestBodyString UTF8String]length:[requestBodyString length]];

 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"
 [request setHTTPBody:requestBody];
 [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"]; // added from first suggestion
```

Comment: i got a OK from the script.... but the variables weren't right... i edited the question

Comment: worked just the same - but still not passing through the variables correctly 


then i tried this

NSString *requestBodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comment=%@&email=%@", message , userEmailString];

notice the = replacing the : ..... that seemed to fix the problem!
YAY!

Answer (score 1):

try to use
`@"comment=%@&email=%@"` instead of `@"comment:%@&email%@"`